# How to return ICollection of Interfaces in MassTransit response?

Tags: c#, .net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

So I have something like this.

```
public interface IFoundUserDataResponse
    {
        string UserName { get; }
        string DisplayName { get; }
        string Email { get; }        
        ICollection<INotifications> Notifications { get; }
    }
```

My class looks like this

```
 public class User
    {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string UserName { get; set; }
     public string DisplayName{ get; set; }
     public string Email{ get; set; }
     public ICollection<Notification> Notifications { get; set; }
    }
```

And in MassTransit response I have this, everything is mapped except of Notifications. I always get null in response no matter what i try.

```
public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IProfileDataRequest> context)
        {
            var user = await _userService.GetProfileByUsernameAsync(context.Message.UserName);
            await context.RespondAsync<IFoundUserDataResponse>(new
                {
                    user.UserName,
                    user.DisplayName,
                    user.Email,               
                    user.Notifications
                }); 
        }
```

I guess I need to map `List<Notification>` to `List<INotification>` but how ???

Answer (score 1):

You might change the message contract to either `IList<INotification>` or `IEnumerable<INotification>`, or even an array `INotification[]`.

The message initializer should convert the collection types as needed. As long as `Notification` is structurally compatible with `INotification`, the properties of the element type should be converted over as well.